# How to parse complex nested xml file in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

i am new to xml parsing not able to decide how to parse this complex xml file in java .
I am able to parse simple xml file but when when it comes to complex xml file i am confused .Not able to read elements of xml using java .
Here is my sample xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:ContentEnvelope xsi:schemaLocation="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/Fundamental/2011-07-07/ 
https://theshare.jso.com/sites/TRM-IA/Content%20Marketplace/Strategic%20Data%20Interfaces/SDI%20Schemas/Schemas/Fundamentals/2015-09-25/FundamentalMaster.xsd"
    xmlns:esg="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/ESGSupportingInfo/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:md="http://data.schemas.financial.jso.com/metadata/2010-10-10/"
    xmlns:cr="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/CoraxData/2012-10-25/"
    xmlns:ful="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FundamentalLineItem/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:fun="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/Fundamental/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:ir="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialInstrumentRelationship/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:fl="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialLineItem/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:pe="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialPeriod/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:seg="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialSegment/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:sr="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialSource/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:sli="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/StandardizedLineItem/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:ss="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/StandardizedStatement/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:fs="http://fundamental.schemas.financial.jso.com/FinancialStatement/2011-07-07/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:env="http://data.schemas.tfn.jso.com/Envelope/2008-05-01/" minVers="1.0" majVers="3" pubStyle="Message">
    <env:Header>
        <env:Info>
            <env:Id>urn:uuid:069527ab-2c10-48bb-b3d2-206f4e66e5d2</env:Id>
            <env:TimeStamp>2016-12-23T10:09:09+00:00</env:TimeStamp>
        </env:Info>
        <fun:OrgId>20240</fun:OrgId>
        <fun:PartitionId>1</fun:PartitionId>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body minVers="0.0" majVers="1" contentSet="Fundamental">
        <env:ContentItem action="Insert">
            <env:Data xsi:type="fun:FundamentalDataItem">
                <fun:Fundamental effectiveTo="9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="2013-06-29T00:55:15.313+00:00" uniqueFuamentalSet="0054341342">
                    <fun:OrganizationId objectType="Organization" objectTypeId="404510">42565596</fun:OrganizationId>
                    <fun:PrimaryReportingEntityCode>A4C67</fun:PrimaryReportingEntityCode>
                    <fun:TotalPrimaryReportingShares>567923000.00000</fun:TotalPrimaryReportingShares>
                    <fun:LocalLanguageId>505074</fun:LocalLanguageId>
                    <fun:IndustryGroups>
                        <fun:IndustryGroup validTo="9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00" validFrom="1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00">
                            <fun:GroupCode>BNK</fun:GroupCode>
                            <fun:GroupName languageId="505074">Bank</fun:GroupName>
                            <fun:TaxonomyId>1</fun:TaxonomyId>
                            <fun:IndustryGroupCodeId>3011649</fun:IndustryGroupCodeId>
                        </fun:IndustryGroup>
                    </fun:IndustryGroups>
                    <fun:GaapCode>CAG</fun:GaapCode>
                    <fun:ConsolidationBasis>Consolidated</fun:ConsolidationBasis>
                    <fun:IsFiling>true</fun:IsFiling>
                    <fun:ConsolidationBasisId>3013598</fun:ConsolidationBasisId>
                    <fun:GaapCodeId>3011536</fun:GaapCodeId>
                    <fun:Taxonomies>
                        <fun:Taxonomy>1</fun:Taxonomy>
                    </fun:Taxonomies>
                    <fun:WorldScopeIds>
                        <fun:WorldScopeId validTo="9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00" validFrom="2012-03-31T00:00:00+00:00">C12436390</fun:WorldScopeId>
                    </fun:WorldScopeIds>
                </fun:Fundamental>
            </env:Data>
        </env:ContentItem>
```

Comment: You say you want to parse the data, but you don't say why. What do you actually want to do with the data? Parsing XML (in the technical sense of the term) is trivial, it's the processing of the data after parsing that creates all the complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely JAXB will help you here.
Since you are dealing with complex xml files, i would suggest below approach( i agree it's lengthy and manual but shall work fine).

1) Generate xsd schema out of given xml content

2) Create a JAXB project in eclipse and create and empty XSD file and write it with xsd schema generated above

3) To convert .xsd file to pojo Right click on .xsd file and generate JAXB classes

4) Now write a code to un-marshal the data and run it, this should give you a corresponding java class.

Comment: Straightforward, definitly.

Comment: I am going to give a try based on your method ..But there is already xsd mentioned in the xml file will that not work ?

Comment: If you have .xsd file you can start with it

Comment: One more question .I have Master xsd that has many xsd  and using that it creates that xml .So from the master xsd will i be able to create all respective classes or do i have to create seperetly all from individual xsd?

Comment: I would suggest, you to create separate .xsd files and update their path in respective files

Comment: Just be aware that JAXB can get very unwieldy if (a) there are more than about 200 element names, or (b) the schema changes more than once a month or so.

Comment: And another thing to beware of: if you generate the schema to match existing instances, then it might not support everything that can validly appear in documents of this type. It would be better to go to the specification (at jso.com?) and find the "real" schema, rather than trying to reverse engineer it.